# Merging two Javascript arrays three elements at a time

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

Given arrays `arr1`, `arr2`, and `newArr` (for instance):

```
var arr1 = ["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5"]
var arr2 = ["b1", "b2", "b3", "b4", "b5"]
var newArr = ["a1", "a2", "a3", "b1", "b2", "b3", "a4", "a5", "b4", "b5"]
```

I am trying to combine two arrays (`arr1` and `arr2`) into one array (`newArr`), in such a way that `newArr` grabs the first (up to) three elements from `arr1`, then the first (up to) three from `arr2`, then the next (up to) three from `arr1`, etc.

I'd initially approached this by iterating through every element of `arr1` and checking to see if the index is divisible by three (`for (var i = 0)` ... `if (i + 1 % 3 === 0)`), but now I'm thinking that this approach is untenable when `arr1.length % 3 !== 0`.

Also, is there a name for this kind of merge procedure?

Comment: Are your arrays the same length ? Can you be clearer by using really different input arrays?

Comment: Yes - my arrays are the same length.  I'll edit my snippet to distinguish the arrays better.

Comment: _is there a name for this kind of merge procedure_ well, the division is sometimes called [chunking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks); using that question and `concat`ting the results should get you where you want to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about...

```
var arr1 = ["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5"]
var arr2 = ["b1", "b2", "b3", "b4", "b5"]
newArr = []
t1 = t2 = temp = []

while(arr1.length) {
  t1 = arr1.splice(0,3)
  t2 = arr2.splice(0,3)
  temp = t1.concat(t2)
  newArr = newArr.concat(temp)
}
console.log(newArr)
```

Comment: This approach is the most similar to what I ended up going with - keeps it simple.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Excuse me, do you have a minute to talk about our Lord and Savior, recursion?

```
/**
 * @param {number[]} arr1
 * @param {number[]} arr2
 */
function threeMerge(arr1, arr2) {

    /**
    * @param {number[]} arr1
    * @param {number[]} arr2
    * @param {number[]} currentArr
    */
    var threeMergeRecursive = function(arr1, arr2, currentArr) {
        if(arr1.length < 3 || arr2.length < 3){
            return currentArr.concat(arr1, arr2);
    } else if (arr2.length < 3) {
        var resultArr = currentArr.concat(
            arr1.slice(0, 3),
            arr2
        );

        return threeMergeRecursive(
            arr1.slice(0, 3),
            [],
            resultArr
        );
    } else {
            var resultArr = currentArr.concat(
                arr1.slice(0, 3),
                arr1.slice(0, 3)
                );

            return threeMergeRecursive(
                arr1.slice(3),
                arr2.slice(3),
                resultArr);
        }
    };

    return(threeMergeRecursive(arr1, arr2, []));
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Basic solution is to loop with two indexes simultaneously.
Here is solution

```
var arr1 = ["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5"],
    arr2 = ["b1", "b2", "b3", "b4", "b5"],
    newArr = [];

for (let a=0, b=0; a<arr1.length || b<arr2.length; ) {
  if (a==b) {
    newArr.push(...arr1.slice(a,a+=3)) }
  else {
    newArr.push(...arr2.slice(b,b+=3)) }
}
```

Please notice sample code use `let` and array unboxing ES6 features.